How do i style tawk.to position in Next Js Script
I am trying to customize the Tawk.to the Sticky button position on my Next js website with CSS but not working.
Here is my script in the Next Js script tag
<Script dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: `
      var Tawk_API=Tawk_API||{}, Tawk_LoadStart=new Date();
      (function(){
      var s1=document.createElement("script"),s0=document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];    
      s1.async=true;
      s1.src='https://embed.tawk.to/66706a619a809f19fb3eb4bb/1i0jhv3q8';
      s1.charset='UTF-8';
      s1.setAttribute('crossorigin','*');
      s0.parentNode.insertBefore(s1,s0);
      })();
      `,
}}
/>

Tried solution: Added tawkWidget ID and styled with CSS but not working
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
      var tawkWidget = document.querySelector('iframe[title="chat widget"]');
      if (tawkWidget) {
            tawkWidget.id = 'tawk-to-widget';
      }
});

CSS:
#tawk-to-widget {
      bottom: 50px !important;
}


I hope this works for you.
useEffect(() => {
    const injectTawkScript = () => {
      const script = document.createElement('script');
      script.type = 'text/javascript';
      script.async = true;
      script.src = 'https://embed.tawk.to/xxxxxxxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxx';
      script.charset = 'UTF-8';
      script.setAttribute('crossorigin', '*');
      document.body.appendChild(script);
      return script;
    };

    const configureTawkAPI = () => {
      const isRTL = themeDirection === 'rtl';
      window.Tawk_API = window.Tawk_API || {};
      window.Tawk_API.customStyle = {
        visibility: {
          desktop: {
            position: isRTL ? 'bl' : 'br',
            xOffset: isRTL ? '20px' : '60px',
            yOffset: 20,
          },
          mobile: {
            position: isRTL ? 'bl' : 'br',
            xOffset: 0,
            yOffset: 0,
          },
          bubble: {
            rotate: '0deg',
            xOffset: isRTL ? 20 : -20,
            yOffset: 0,
          },
        },
      };
    };

    const script = injectTawkScript();
    configureTawkAPI();

    return () => {
      document.body.removeChild(script);
    };
  }, [themeDirection]);


Thanks for your answer. It could use some more explanations. Please [edit] it to add more details.

I have encountered this recently. Since tawk.to doesn't provide any method to change the CSS properties, you'll have to modify it after the widget mounts.
Here's how you can do it:

I'm using TawkMessengerReact to connect tawk.to with my website.



import React, { forwardRef } from "react";
import TawkMessengerReact from "@tawk.to/tawk-messenger-react";

const TawkMessenger = forwardRef((props, ref: React.Ref<TawkMessengerReact>) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <TawkMessengerReact
        propertyId="YOUR_PROPERTY_ID"
        widgetId="YOUR_WIDGET_ID"
        ref={ref}
      />
    </div>
  );
});

export default TawkMessenger;




Then modify the widget like this:



  useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      const tawkIframe = document.querySelector("iframe[title='chat widget']") as HTMLIFrameElement;
      
      if (tawkIframe) {
        const tawkDoc = tawkIframe.contentDocument || tawkIframe.contentWindow.document;
        if (tawkDoc) {
          const tawkStyle = tawkDoc.createElement("style");
          tawkStyle.innerHTML = `
            .tawk-min-container {
              transform: scale(0.6) !important; 
              transform-origin: bottom right !important;
            }
          `;
          tawkDoc.head.appendChild(tawkStyle);
          clearInterval(interval);
        }
      }
    }, 100);
  }, []);



Here, you can target any of the classes of the widget and apply your CSS accordingly.
